# How to change a dropdown in an F# Canopy UI Testing Script

Tags: asp.net, testing, f#, canopy-web-testing

I am really enjoying using **[Canopy Web Testing](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/index.html)** to test out my .NET Web Apps with F#. However the documentation is sparse. I'm looking for a hint on how to change an HTML `select` tag to select an element based on a `value` of an option.

Right now, all I can manage to do is calling the `click` event from Canopy, and then firing `press down` the correct number of times in my test to get to the proper element. Of course, this means my tests all break if the number of elements in the dropdown changes.

Does anyone have an idea of how to use the `option` tag's value to select it in the UI?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
open canopy
open runner

start firefox

"taking canopy for a spin" &&& fun _ ->
    url "http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/testpages/"

    "#item_list" << read "option[value='2']"

    "#item_list" == "Item 2"

run()
```

You could write your own helper method to improve this by doing

```
let option value = read <| sprintf "option[value='%s']" value

"taking canopy for a spin" &&& fun _ ->
    url "http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/testpages/"

    "#item_list" << option "2"
    "#item_list" == "Item 2"
```

I will open an issue and add a feature so that you can do the below instead

```
    "#item_list" << "2"
```

Comment: Wow, that you so much for your reply, and for opening that issue. I think Canopy is absolutely fantastic so far.

Comment: Glad you like it!  Thanks for the feedback.