# F# Canopy Select or Dropdown with Option Group

Tags: f#, web-testing, canopy-web-testing

How do you select an option or set the value in a select list that has option groups?

This method does not work: [How to change a dropdown in an F# Canopy UI Testing Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021251/how-to-change-a-dropdown-in-an-f-canopy-ui-testing-script)

sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="test-select">
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Canopy Test:

```
open canopy
open runner
open Helpers

    let all() =
    context "OptGroup Tests"

    let page = ""

    ntest ("Testing page " + page) (fun _ ->
        let mUrl = testpage.html
        url mUrl

        "#test-select" << "Audi"
    )
```

Comment: Why does this method not work? What happens? Have you tried anything else? What results did you get?

Comment: The test times out looking for the element. If I remove the option groups it is able to set the value. I have tried executing some js, and it is able to select it then, however it needs to be more user friendly to QA. All my other selects work without optgroup.

Comment: Could it have to do with capitalization? (i.e. `Audi` vs `audi`)

Comment: I am actually trying to select it by text value, not option value. That was a poor example I guess. Like I said without the optgroup it works.

Comment: Its probably an oversite in canopy.  I will work to fix this problem.